# Chronurgist Wizard's Chronal Shift at advantage/disadvantage

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, advantage-and-disadvantage

During my session a player come under the effects of the Dominate Monster spell during a combat. The player, rolled at advantage as written in the spells description, but failed the Wisdom DC both times. The Chronurgist Wizard used his Chronal Shift to reroll as a reaction, but we debated if the roll should be at advantage or not.

I can't find anything online that would contradict other wise, and the closest thing I can find from the PHB states:

''When you have advantage or disadvantage and ''something in the game'', such as the halfling’s Lucky trait, lets you reroll the d20, you can reroll only one of the dice''

So, how would Chronal Shift be applied in this instance? Would the played roll again at advantage, or would they roll a further 1d20? I personally made the ruling as it being 1d20.

Comment: Does the following answer your question: "[If you have dis/advantage on a roll, do you have dis/advantage on a reroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129934)"? If it does not, a comment or edit explaining why would be helpful for answerers

Comment: Hi James, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance. Thanks for telling us that you're asking about D&D 5e. I've edited it out of the question, but so long as the [dnd-5e] tag is still there, that's good enough for us (tags are typically our preferred way of specifying the game and edition), and I've added a few other tags too. Just as another tip, the [dungeons-and-dragons] tag is usually only used for questions about multiple editions of D&D, so you only need the [dnd-5e] tag for this question. Happy gaming!

Comment: (If anyone is wondering about the bounty removal and reclosing, please see the convo in general chat starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56404496#56404496))